# JQuery Set selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have two selection boxes, the default value is - and i want to pick something else for both, my first problem is both fields have dynamic id like `prod-685209-Size` so i'm having trouble accessing with id.

I have the following HTML:

```
<select class="sku-attr" name="Size">
<option value="_def">-</option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>

<select class="sku-attr" name="Color">
    <option value="_def">-</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

So i executed the following:

`document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex = 2`

`document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1].selectedIndex = 2`

It worked on the front side, showing my new options but it didn't prompt the backend as it is not actually selecting the options. Backend works fine when i click to these options by hand, basically i need another solution to choose these options.

Comment: If not getting submitted properly something wrong in when you run that code. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: _but it didn't prompt the backend_ -- yes because the script executed on the front-end. Can you post what code notifies the back-end for the change of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add .validate() after your dom commands to actually prompt the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your requirement then you need something like this. Just add two different **ids** to your `select` element and attach a `change` event listener. For example **size** and **color**

```js
var s = document.getElementById("size");
var c = document.getElementById("color");

function getSize() {
  sizeSelected = s.value;
  console.log('size=' + sizeSelected);
}

function getColor() {
  colorSelected = c.value;
  console.log('color=' + colorSelected);
}

s.addEventListener('change', getSize);
c.addEventListener('change', getColor);
```

```html
<select id="size" class="sku-attr" name="Size">
  <option value="_def">-</option>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
  <option value="XL">XL</option>
</select>

<select id="color" class="sku-attr" name="Color">
  <option value="_def">-</option>
  <option value="Black">Black</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```